# How to use table alias to distinguish multiple properties after joining MySQL tables using groovy

Tags: mysql, sql, groovy

How can I distinguish properties from diffent tables after a join using table aliases?

As a simplified example, I have two tables with a lot of properties, the property names aren't unique, both table have an `id` - for example.

Now - I have the following exemplary query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA ta INNER JOIN tableB tb ON ta.id = tb.a_id
```

How can I get the value of both 'id' properties?

The following didn't work:

```
def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_SERVER}/${MYSQL_TABLE}", MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASSWORD, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
sql.eachRow (query){ row ->
    println "ID of the 'table a object' : ${row['ta.id']}"
    println "ID of the 'table b object' : ${row['tb.id']}"
}
```

With this, I get the following error: `java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name ta.id`

My temporary - but not desired - solution is to specify the properties in the query:

```
SELECT ta.id as aID, tb.id as bID, * FROM tableA ta INNER JOIN tableB tb ON ta.id = tb.a_id
```

Both `tableA` and `tableB` have a lot of properties - potentially duplicated - which I don't want respectively can't specify by hand.

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: I don't know Groovy, but conceptually you can iterate over the resultset metadata to build a map from [`getTableName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getTableName(int))+[`getColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName(int)) to column index, then use that map to access the columns by index.

Comment: I tried that but `getTableName` returned an empty string. I hoped it exists a more groovy way - but if the info isn't in the meta data, how should groovy extract the infos? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have a working example of what you are explaining:

```
sql.eachRow("select * from Group_ G inner join Organization_ O on G.name = O.organizationId")  { row ->
    println "${row['G.name']} ${row['O.name']}"
}
```

From your code, what I see is that:

```
ON ta.id = tb.a_id
```

are not the same properties you are trying to access:

```
row['ta.id']
row['tb.id'] // tb.a_id?
```

Comment: Thats what I want to do - but I can't access `row['G.name']` - and no `tb.id` isn't the same like `tb.a_id` - it was just an example, you could set any join condition you want.

Comment: Which version of groovy are you using?

Comment: It seems to be solved in groovy 1.7.5 (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-3320)

Comment: It is working for me with groovy 1.8.6, MySQL 5.5.12 and mysql connector 5.1.18.

Comment: Ok - I thought it is a general issue, but it isn't. Then I have to do some investigations for my (special) configuration. Thank you!